# why network clock is required in the router?

Tags: switch, router, ethernet, pseudowire

what is the usage of network clock in the router? Is it something to do only with pseudowire T1/E1? What I am looking is the need of network clock - syncE in the router? What is the significance? Why is it important for any router to support so?

Comment: Which router model/OS?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the usage of network clock in the router?

Of course it has uses, though generally unrelated with classic router functions.

> Is it something to do only with pseudowire T1/E1?

This is one typical usage. Notice that not every router performs TDM-related functions.

> What I am looking is the need of network clock - syncE in the router?

SyncE is one method for providing high accuracy clocking for TDM over packet protocols.
Another mechanism is "IEEE 1588-2008 Precision Time Protocol".

> What is the significance? Why is it important for any router to support so?

There are functions, like E1 over pseudowire, which demand high precision clock synchronization.
But not every router performs those functions.